# Run script that has been loaded by Javascript on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm loading a script by Javascript after an ajax call. For this I'm using this code:

```js
var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.src = 'https://www.example.com/scripts/form.js';
imported.type = 'text/javascript';
document.head.appendChild(imported);
```

This Javascript file *(`https://www.example.com/scripts/form.js`)* will run on Google Chrome, Edge and Firefox after it's added to the `head` of the document, but not on IE 11. What code must I add to execute that script on IE?

Answer (score 0):

I've found if after Googling I've just added this line of code before I add it to the `head`.

```js
imported.onreadystatechange = function () { }; // For IE 11
```